# How does the runtime of a hashCode() function affect the runtime of Hash Tables?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashcode, trie

I'm getting confused about the time complexity of hash tables in general.

I understand that insert, search, etc. are amortized O(1) time due to resizing, the fact that array accesses after computing a hashcode are constant time, that we can always keep the load factor of the hash table to a constant value, and that good hashcodes enable us to have minimal collisions.

However, my question is about the runtime of the hashCode() itself.

My understand is that insert(), get(), etc. rely on computing the hashcode first and then, conventionally, storing a given item at index i = hashCode() % buckets.length

This seems to conflict with the amortized O(1) performance of the hashtable, because O(1) performance seems to assume that computing a hashcode is constant time.

However, from my understanding, for many recursive objects (such as a linked list), we compute the hashcode recursively (I'm omitting the base case for simplicity):

`hashcode():
   return this.item.hashCode() + 31 * this.next.hashCode()`

Wouldn't this mean that hashCode() has O(N) runtime and thus insert() for the hashtable would have O(N) runtime?

If this is the case, then wouldn't insert() for hashtables be pretty bad for items which are being inserted which have slow hashCode() functions? Even for something like inserting a String, doesn't this mean that insert() would be O(N) where N is the length of the string, since we compute the hashcode based on each character in the string?

I've seen hashcodes become cached before, but caching only happens for a particular instance of an object, which means we need to insert the same instance of an object multiple times in order for caching to have an effect, which doesn't seem particularly helpful in practical scenarios.

If what I'm saying is correct, then, does this mean that for some sequential data such as strings, a Trie would have better performance since its insert() and get() would be O(L) worst case where L is the length of the item/sequence being inserted - is this the point of Tries?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. In the case of Java specifically (since your example looks Java-like) the String class *caches* the `hashCode()` value to make it an amortized O(1) operation again. But even that doesn't always help, as you correctly observe.

Comment: There's a great article in the latest Communications of the ACM about how Big O analysis can be misleading because it focuses on worst case performance, but worst case may not be the case you're actually worried about. The short answer is: don't assume something is fast (or slow!): instead *measure* for your particular situation.